# Matlab - 8x8 window and finding mean

Tags: matlab, matrix, window, mean

Say I have a matrix of an image, and I want to do the following:

- Slide an `8x8` window over the matrix
- Calculate the mean for each pixel in the matrix

How can I do that in `matlab`, provided that I'm kind of new to coding in matlab.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered what you want to happen near the edges?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to make something like a [median filter](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html), but then using `mean` as the kernel?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `conv2` with a `ones(8)` filter, as in `I2 = conv2(I, 1.0 / 64.0 * ones(8), 'valid');`. We divide by 64.0 because the "filter" isn't normalized.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Will that work for sliding te window over the matrix?

Comment: Yes, both @natan's and my solution will slide the mean filter over the matrix. `conv2` will be a tiny little bit faster, but both solutions are correct.

Comment: @s.bandra, won't you rather use `same` instead of `valid`?  using `same` keeps the original image size... It is not the `valid` is wrong mathwise, just makes life easier downstream

Comment: Whatever the OP is happier with, but `same` will not be correct on the borders, and you can always use `size`... but yeah, either is fine. Same problem with `nlfilter` by the way!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`nlfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html) :

```
fun = @(x) mean(x(:)); 
ans= nlfilter(img,[8 8],fun);
```

But as @s.bandara suggested, the `conv2` is **much** faster for just calculating the mean...
Note that the matrix size will change when using the `conv2` with `valid`.

[image]

`nlfilter` Elapsed time is 0.433989 seconds.

`conv2`    Elapsed time is 0.000803 seconds.

So it is pretty obvious that for the task of finding the mean, `conv2` is much much faster.

Comment: I think he wants a sliding window, not tiling.

Comment: @natan.Thanks for your kind reply. Will that work for sliding te window over the matrix?

Comment: yes it will. `nlfilter` is a general sliding-neighborhood operations function that can take fancier functions than just `mean`, so it is a bit of an overkill. The `conv2` should also work, I'd replace the `valid` input to `same` though...

Comment: @natan, very useful, +1. I would suggest against `same` because of order effects.

Answer (score 0):

try to extract first the sub-matrices of your image like in here: [MATLAB Submatrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/submatrix.html)

then use the [mean(A)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) function for each submatrices