# Finding energy on a window with specified dimensions using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, energy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating energy using MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599816)

Energy is defined as follows:

[image]

I'm planning to do the following:

1- Slide a window with dimensions 4X4 on an image

2- For each window calculate the `energy`

3- Find the histogram

For sliding the window over an image, I know that we can use `nlfilter`, but this requires a `fun`. Will this function be the energy? How can I use this with `nlfiler`?

So, how do you think I can go with 1,2, and 3 in MATLAB?

Comment: Hint for #1: square the image element-wise and filter with a `ones(4)` mask.

Comment: you just got the answer for #2 in your previous question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599816/matlab-calculating-energy

Comment: And #3 was answered too in a previous question of yours... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454338/matlab-8x8-window-and-finding-mean

Answer (score 1):

Summing up all the answers you got from previous questions (some by me):

```
fun = @(x) sum(x(:).^2)/sum(x(:)).^2; 
en= nlfilter(img,[4 4],fun);
bins= 100 ; %# or whatever number of bins you want
hist(en(:),linspace(min(en(:)),max(en(:)),bins));
```

Comment: Because of the way @Med-SWEng wanted the `energy` to be compatible with `graycoprops` (see my comment to the question). I've also used the slow `nlfilter` and not `conv2` because that's what he\she wanted... I should add the `conv2` just for showing how fast it'll be...

Comment: yep, you also told him that already...

Comment: Yeah. And I apologize for the tone. These fire-and-forget questions sometimes get me. I'll be removing my comments now.